# Modernizr reports no-overflowscrolling even for modern desktop browsers?

Tags: cross-browser, overflow, modernizr

I want to have a max-height div with scrollbars when the content goes beyond the max-height:

```
<div id="scrollable-div">A bunch of content that might be long.</div>

#scrollable-div {
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

The problem is that this is not supported in older mobile browsers (such as Android < 3.0). So I want to use Modernizr to detect the overflow scrolling support, and fall back to no max-height when the support is not there (as suggested here: [Android browser bug? div overflow scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013204/android-browser-bug-div-overflow-scrolling/13379411#13379411)):

```
#scrollable-div {
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.no-overflowscrolling #scrollable-div {
  max-height: none;    
}
```

However, Modernizr is adding the `no-overflowscrolling` class even in modern desktop browsers where I know that `overflow: auto` works. I've tested with Firefox 24.0, Chrome 30.0.1599.101, and Safari 6.0.5 (8536.30.1), and Modernizr adds `no-overflowscrolling` for each. Furthermore, `Modernizr.overflowscrolling` returns `false` in the javascript consoles.

I suspect there is something I'm not understanding here. Can somebody explain?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what I was not understanding. Modernizr's `overflowscrolling` test is for the `-*-overflow-scrolling` CSS property that some browsers implement. It is not a test for whether `overflow:[auto|scroll]` works in the browser. `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` is an additional css property that controls whether scrolling in iOS will have "momentum" like native iOS controls. It is obviously not supported in desktop browsers because it is a mobile-specific property; that's why Modernizr adds the `no-overflowscrolling` class.

**overflowscrolling != support for overflow: scroll**