# scroll bar not visible in popup

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]   I need scroll bar.. scroll bar not displayed in mobile.. this is my html code but this code is in js:

```
Here modal as css that diaplay popup:


'<div id="modal">'+
    '   <div class="modal-content">'+
    '       <div class="cf footerPop" style="margin-top: -15px; ">'+
    '           <span align="center">Countries</span>'+
    '       </div>'+        
    '   <div class="copyPop" style="height:300px; overflow:scroll; "  >'+
    '    <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;" ><span id="countriesBlock" name="country"  >'+conSelect+' </span></a>'+
    '       </div>'+
    '       <div class="cf footerPop">'+
    '           <a href="#" class="btnClose"><span align="center">Close</span></a>'+
    '       </div>'+
    '   </div>'+
    '   <div class="overlay"></div>'+
    '</div>';
```

Please any one help me..

[image]

Comment: Are you able to screengrab, and perhaps tell us more about the platform you are testing (iOS, Android...)? Thanks.

Comment: scroll bar not visible in popup.. In higher version scrolling done but in lower version nothing will happen..

Comment: If it's an older Android OS (< v3 ) I think this StackOverflow question might be worth reviewing first. Let us know if any of these suggestions solve your problem. If not, I'll put my thinking cap back on. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013204/

Comment: Even if the scrollbar isn't visible, does it still scroll?

Comment: please tell me how to overcome this problem..